# Pandas: Pivot a typed dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have data in the following format:

```
Time, Type, Subtype, Value
0,A,Ab,1
0,A,Ac,2
0,B,Ba,1
```

And I need:

```
Time, Type-A-Ab-Value, Type-A-Ac-Value, Type-B-Ba-Value
0, 1, 2, 1
```

Is there a pandas primitive that will solve this problem in one stroke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to set the multilevel index then use [`DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) on the levels `1, 2` to reshape the dataframe, then use `.map` to flatten the `MultiIndex` columns:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Time', 'Type', 'Subtype']).unstack(level=[1, 2])
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda s: 'Type-' + '-'.join(s[1:]) + '-Value')
```

OR, it is also possible to use [`DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df['pvt'] = 'Type-' + df['Type'] + '-' + df['Subtype'] + '-Value'
df1 = df.pivot('Time', 'pvt', 'Value').rename_axis(columns=None)
```

Result:

```
print(df1)

      Type-A-Ab-Value  Type-A-Ac-Value  Type-B-Ba-Value
Time                                                   
0                   1                2                1
```